# Android Activities UI Persistence

Tags: android, user-interface, persistence, android-activity

I need to have two activities in an Android app that can be switched between each other with UI persistence as follows:

1. Activity A launches Activity B.
2. User triggers some UI changes in Activity B.
3. Activity B returns to Activity A (by a call to `onBackPressed()` or something similar)
4. Activity A re-launches Activity B.

I would like the changes made in step 2 to be visible in step 4.

I have tried using the `singleInstance` activity tag on Activity B to no avail.  I would also prefer a more elegant solution than simply writing all object properties to a file or SQLite table.
It seems that this behaviour must be easily achievable given that Android does it automatically for calls to `onBackPressed()` where the parent Activity's UI is saved.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Activity A launches Activity B

.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Launch Activity B from Activity A using startActivityForResult.

> User triggers some UI changes in
>   Activity B

.

> Activity B returns to Activity A (by a
>   call to onBackPressed() or something
>   similar)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("change_value1", change1);
                    intent.putExtra("change_value2", change2);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
```

Activity A re-launches Activity B.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        /*
         * Gets invoked on finish() from ActivityB.class
         */
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){
        case 0:

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String change1, change2;
                    change1 = data.getStringExtra("change_value1");
                change2 = data.getStringExtra("change_value2");
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                                startActivity(intent); 
            }
        }
    }
```

You can read more about intents [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I was still hoping for a cleaner approach. Intuitively, I expect one to exist because of the way android handles switching back to the parent activity. I suppose this is the best way to go for now then. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @aandroid - It's pretty intuitive if you're familiar with event handling.  You're still launching the activity via an `Intent`, nothing new there.  Activity A is simply handling the results of activity B via a callback handler.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist data between multiple activities it's best to create a subclass of Application and put your objects in there. Then each activity you spawn can get hold of the same objects.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)